# Click of a button not working when clicked through modal in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working with modal popup in angular which involves a submit button in the modal popup. The modal popup calls from a parent component.
I have click event for the button which is for submit button but its not getting triggered.
It should log when I click on the submit button.
[image: Modal Popup which has submit button]

Parent html

```
 <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
 <button (click)="openModal(modal)" >open modal</button>
 <app-modal #modal [active]="isActive"> </app-modal>
```

modal.component.html //Child component

```
    <div [hidden]="!active">
  
    <div class="modal-background">
    </div>
  
    <div  class="modal">
      <div class="modal-body">
       <h1>algun titulo</h1>
       <p>algun contenido</p>
       <button onSubmit="onSubmit()">
         Submit
       </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

modal.component.ts (child component)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './modal.component.css' ]
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() active: boolean ;

  ngOnInit() {
   
  }

  openModal(value) {
    value.active = true
  }

  onSubmit(){
    debugger;
    console.log('submit--->');
  }

  closeModal(value) {
    value.active = false
  }

}
```